# variable not working in shell script inside sed

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

i have variable `jr=127.0.1.1 ysrnsk`. i have to replace it to second line of my `/etc/hosts` file . `sudo sed -i.bak '2 s/^.*$/'$jr'/' /etc/hosts`
this is what i have done. But it doesn't provide any output

Answer (score 0):

The sed command doesn't output anything since you are using -i option

And you must double quote everything:

```
jr="127.0.1.1 ysrnsk"
sudo sed -i.bak "2 s/^.*$/$jr/" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Actually jr variable is not a user set variable. It is an output from other combined commands

Comment: jr=`cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.1.1 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'| sed 's/$/ '$host'/$

Comment: @sysadmincrispy that's fine. It should still work. Note: using `jr=`` is quite an old method. For readability, use `jr=$(...)`. Secondly, you are piping a lot. Just as an example you can combine `cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.1.1` to be just `grep 127.0.1.1 /etc/hosts`

Comment: This line sudo sed -i.bak "2 s/^.*$/$jr/" /etc/hosts doesn't write any output to /etc/hosts. but in terminal as a single command it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
jr="127.0.1.1 ysrnsk"
```

^^ Providing Quotes here, means encompass all the data, otherwise your input is only 127.0.1.1

```
sed -i.bak '2 s/^.*$/$jr/' /etc/hosts
```

`-i` argument makes the edit in place. Which does not provide output. If you want to "test" your output before you edit just run

```
sed .bak "2 s/^.*$/'$jr'/" /etc/hosts
```

`''` in bash is literally what you type in. To allow parameter expansion, such as turning your variables into their actual meanings use double quotes `""`

```
sed .bak "2 s/^.*$/'$jr'/" /etc/hosts
                   ^   ^ These don't do anything, other than again, tell bash to interpret this literally
```

So:

```
sed .bak "2 s/^.*$/$jr/" /etc/hosts # This to see your output
sed -i .bak "2 s/^.*$/$jr/" /etc/hosts # This to commit it without output
```

Comment: Actually jr variable is not a user set variable. It is an output from other combined commands

Comment: jr=`cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.1.1 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'| sed 's/$/ '$host'/$

Comment: @sysadmincrispy Can you explain what this part is supposed to do? `sed 's/$/ '$host'/$`